# Need help building simple recursive function

Tags: python, function, recursion

I have an array that has 93 numbers in it. I need to make a running total of them so I need to build a function that goes something like SUM = n*G0 + (n-1)*G1 + (n-2)*G3 + ... Gn

But i dont know how to make a for loop that does that

It would kinda look like this at first
SUM_0 = G0,SUM_1 = G1+2*G0,SUM_2 G2+2*G1+3*G0, SUM_4 G3+2*G2+3*G1+4*G0

etc...

Comment: We're gonna need a bit more information on what exactly youre trying to do

Comment: Please explain what are H0, H1,.. Hn. I guess they are the elements of the array...

Comment: Yes they are elements of an array. They are numbers, I'm trying to do a running sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function will give you the `sum` that you are looking for. As for the sequece, please add one more example.

```
def mysum(my_array):
    n = len(my_array)
    sum = 0
    for i, j in enumerate(my_array):
        sum += (n - i)*j
    return sum
```

Here is how to get the sequences.

```
def subsum(an_array):
    l = len(an_array)
    if l == 1:
        return an_array[0]
    else:
        return sum([i*j for i, j in list(zip(an_array[::-1], range(1, l+1)))])
def sequence_from(my_array):
    seq = []
    for i, j in enumerate(my_array):
        seq.append(subsum(my_array[:i+1]))
    return seq
sequence_from([1,2,3,4, 6])

>>>[1, 4, 10, 20, 36]
```

The first function `subsum` takes an array and applies the sequence definition on that array before returning the solution.

The second function `sequence_from` extends `subsum` to get the final sequence that you want.

Comment: I added another example, I don't need just the sum, though, its a running count so it needs to be multiplied by those numbers

Comment: @JuliaGorman please see my edited answer. I am typing an explanation

Comment: @JuliaGorman could you up vote my answer and accept it if it solved your problem?

Comment: OP mentions *recursion* in both the title and tags but I don't see any recursion in this solution.

Comment: @SamuelNde I can't upvote bc I dont have that privilege yet

Comment: @JuliaGorman No problem but you can use the little checkmark below the downvote button to accept the answer. As the person who posted this question, you have the special privillege to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is both titled and tagged "recursion", here's a simple recursive solution:

```
def calculation(numbers):
    if numbers:
        previous = calculation(numbers[:-1])
        return previous + [sum(numbers) + (previous[-1] if previous else 0)]

    return []

my_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

print(calculation(my_numbers))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
[1, 4, 10, 20, 35, 56, 84, 120, 165, 220]
>
```